# How to in PHP / HTML to pass a specific class name to specific tag

Tags: php, html, class

I'm still new to Front End Development and working on my first really big site / wordpress blog.

So my question is this, I have a Menu that will be the same on all pages on the site. However each section will have it's name highlighted in the Menu Nav.

Current Nav_Bar markup:

```
<div id="nav_bar">

    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav_li"><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav_li selected"><a href="#blog_content">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Book</a></li>
        <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Media</a></li>
        <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

        <li class="search">
            <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search') { this.value = ''; }" value="Search" />

        </li>

        <li class="search_btn">
            <a href="#" title="Lets find it!"><div class="search_button">Go</div></a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div><!-- nav_bar -->
```

Now I've build pages before using this simple PHP code: `<?php include("menu.php"); ?>`

However, how would you guys 1st: organize this menu to accept and incoming value, like menu.php+select="home" and 2nd how would you pass in that value to add a class of selected to one of the Menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the include, set a value in some parameter, like `$page = 'blog'` and then in the menu.php

```
<li class="nav_li<?php echo $page === 'blog' ? " selected='selected'" : "" ?>"><a href="#blog_content">Blog</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Though I had to change it to: <?php echo $page === 'services' ? " selected" : "" ?>

Comment: So you have a ternary operator embedded into every `<a />`?

Comment: @msanford yes. It's not the most elegant solution, but it works (even if the client has disabled Javascript).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want your 'incoming value' for the purpose of highlighting a menu item (rather than displaying a particular page)? It's unnecessary, because the browser already knows what page it's on.

This is one way of highlighting the current page in jQuery:

```js
$('.nav li a').each(function(){
  var link = $(this).attr('href'),
    current_page = location.href;
  if(current_page.indexOf(link) != -1) {
      $(this).addClass('current-page');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First off your class on li "nav_li" is redundant and could be removed. Use .nav li in place to ref these list items with less lines of code. This works both as a JQuery selector and CSS selector. Second, to answer you actual question; I would use the active class as follows:

```
// Assuming the following html. <ul class="nav"><li><a href="/about.php">About</a></li></ul>    

$('.nav li').click(function() {
    $('.nav li.active').removeClass('.active');
    $(this).addClass('.active');
    window.location = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
    return;
});
```

Now in the area where you keep your navbar you check to see if the current url is active by the following:

```
<?php    
$currentUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="<?php if($currentUri == '/about.php') {echo 'active';} ?>"><a href="/about.php">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Add the condition in the php script to each list item.

Sincerely,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using javascript

```
var url=document.location.toString();
if(url=="http://www.something.com/some.php")
{
//code to add class to specific link
}
else if(url=="http://www.something.com/someelse.php")
{
//code to add class to specific link
}
```

You can also do this on server side in menu.php

```
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Then check the url and add class name accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understainding what you're after, maybe something like:

**index.php**:

```
<?php
  $page = 'home';
  // page code ...
?>
```

**about.php**:

```
<?php
  $page = 'about';
  // page code ...
?>
```

etc, etc...

Then **menu.php** tweaked slightly:

```
<div id="nav_bar">

  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav_li home"><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav_li about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav_li blog"><a href="#blog_content">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="nav_li book"><a href="#">Book</a></li>
    <li class="nav_li media"><a href="#">Media</a></li>
    <li class="nav_li events"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li class="nav_li services"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="nav_li contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

    <li class="search">
        <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search') { this.value = ''; }" value="Search" />

    </li>

    <li class="search_btn">
        <a href="#" title="Lets find it!"><div class="search_button">Go</div></a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div><!-- nav_bar -->
```

and finally some javascript:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
   $('#nav_bar li.<?=$page?>').addClass('selected');
  });
</script>
```

That assumes jQuery is being used, but it isn't necessary obviously, the same could be done with straight javascript.

Comment: thanks, I haven't gotten to jQuery or mastered JavaScript yet, so I had to use the 1 PHP only solution